How do I speed up SQL Server inserts using the Airflow BigQueryToMsSqlOperator?
I am trying to use the Airflow operator BigQueryToMsSqlOperator to move a dataset from BigQuery to SQL Server (2019). The dataset is 9 columns of numeric, date, and integer data types. It currently transfers at about 600 rows per minute which will take hours since the entire data set is about 500k rows. Is there a way to speed this up? The target dataset is truncated before insert and is not clustered.
I have tried using the BigQueryToMsSqlOperator and the data transfer is slower than expected.

Try providing a batch_size. try with the high number like 10k, and try to find the sweet spot. However it would be best if you check with your admin, as it could impact SQL Server.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/4.0.0/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_mssql/index.html

thank you! I have tried that with 4k, 7k, and 10k and it's still going very slow.
